# How to structure Java Spring/Hibernate backend for bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am building a twitter clone that has a OneToMany/ManyToOne Relationship with Users and Tweets (One user, many tweets etc).

I am using a bidirectional relationship, and using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to handle the infinite recursion, however, since the infinite recursion has been solved, now I can't get the user information from each tweet.

**Domain Objects:**

User Object

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference
private Set<Tweet> tweets = new HashSet<>();
```

Tweet Object

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonManagedReference
private User user;
```

**API Responses**

GET users (this one looks good)

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alex",
        "tweets": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "tweet": "cook one meal, doesn't make u a chef"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "tweet": "Red fox jumped over the barn"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

GET tweets (this one isn't good, I don't have the user information on each tweet, but if I add it, then there will be infinite recursion again)

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "tweet": "cook one meal, doesn't make u a chef"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "tweet": "Red fox jumped over the barn"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is Json Views. This guide has examples, including ones with Spring https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JsonIgnoreProperties` to tell Hibernate to ignore the property when serializing.

Tweet Object

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("tweets")
private User user;
```

So now when you serialize your Tweet object it will contain all the `User` information **except** the tweets.